# UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION issue

Tags: soap-api, enterprise-wsdl

**I'm using enterprise wsdl in .Net application to run sfdc webservices**. Recently when I try to run the application I keep getting following error. Any idea how to avoid the issue?

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION:
>   Invalid Api version specified on URL    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)

Thanks,
Lahiru

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the API version from app.config file. Was able to run the process after downgrading the API version

```
<applicationSettings>
    <SFServices.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="SFServices_SFDC_ProdV2_SforceService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/**31.0**/0DF40000000GsQU</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="SFServices_servdev2_SforceService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/**32.0**/0DFe00000004D49</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="SFServices_staging_9_24_SforceService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/**34.0**/0DF1900000000HH</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="SFServices_na27_10_24_SforceService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/**35.0**/0DF330000008TUB</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="SFServices_FSB1_14_16_SforceService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/**35.0**/0DF19000000CazJ</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="SFServices_POC_1_14_SforceService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/**35.0**/0DF560000008OSP</value>
        </setting>
    </SFServices.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```